# Does a black hole cool off and obey laws of thermal equilibium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, particle-physics, black-holes

I have read these questions:

[Kirchhoff law of thermal radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74679/kirchhoff-law-of-thermal-radiation)

[Why do dark objects radiate thermal electromagnetic energy faster than light objects?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86317/why-do-dark-objects-radiate-thermal-electromagnetic-energy-faster-than-light-obj?rq=1)

And it made me curious.

Nothing gets out of a black hole, I understand, except Hawking radiation.

Now every object in the universe is trying to get to thermal equilibrium with its environment.

All these answers did not talk about whether the black hole can/does exchange heat with the environment (vacuum).

Since nothing escapes a black hole, is a black hole an exception of the law of thermal equilibrium?

So the black hole stays hot?

Question:

1. Does a black hole try to get to thermal equilibrium with its environment (vacuum)? Or does it stay hot?
2. Does Hawking radiation cool the black hole off or does it only shrink its mass?

Comment: Shrinking the mass of a BH increases its temperature. This is what happens with Hawking radiation.

Comment: A BH is a perfect black body.

Comment: Possible duplicate <https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-kind-of-systems-of-black-holes-satisfy-the-laws-of-black-hole-thermodynamic>

Comment: By the way, Hawking radiation has of course not been measured in any way yet, so the answers above are all theoretical.